# Confirm (enter twice) pw and email at registration - good idea?

Tags: website-design

Many sites seem to require that their users enter their email and password twice during the registration process.  How useful is it really?  It seems it could be a pain in the neck for many users, for limited gains, no?

Thanks,

JDelage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning stems from users not being able to see their password as they type it into the password box. The email field therefore does not require duplication.

For the password field, it can be useful to ensure the user has not mistyped the password. However, if you have a "forgot password" function, then there is no reason the user cannot reset their password if it turns out they mistyped it.

As Michael Pryor suggests in the comments, the fewer form fields you have, the more likely a user will (a) use the form in the first place, and (b) not make any mistakes. [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/) seems to be the current 'poster child' for good registration form UI - they ask for only three fields, the absolute minimum you need to start using the service.

See also this question from the UI Stack Exchange: [Is a “repeat password” field necessary in a signup page?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/484/is-a-repeat-password-field-necessary-in-a-signup-page)

Answer (score 2):

[A/B test](http://www.youtube.com/user/FogCreekSoftware#p/u/1/pDQsfMZQ44A)!

If you are asking if more form fields reduce the number of signups, the answer is definitively yes.

Comment: This is *really* easy to A/B test, and I suggest you do so, but I'll bet serious money that the number of people filling out your form increases in exact proportion to how few form fields you require.

Answer (score 2):

Probably is a pain in the neck for users. But it improves the reliability of the data you're collecting.

Its a trade off based on how important it is for you (and your users) to get the right data first time.

Comment: Many people like me, copy and paste email id & password always. still it should be retype manually for reliability

Comment: Yes I do that too.

Answer (score 2):

One option that's been debated, is to make the password field *visible text*, instead of asterisks. That way, the user can see what is being typed, and you don't need a second field. (Ideally make it an option, say a checkbox, so the user can make it visible or not).

- [Stop Password Masking](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/passwords.html)
- [The problem with passwords](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/the-problem-with-passwords/)

And I personally *never* re-type my email field, instead just cutting/pasting it - so it's kinda pointless to duplicate that one also...